# Undefined method 'brands_count' BigCommerce gem

Tags: ruby, bigcommerce

I'm starting to get my head around the BigCommerce gem 0.9.0 (https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-ruby) and am having troubles with the Brands resource. I'm not experienced enough to know whether I'm doing something wrong (highly likely) or if it's a bug (not so likely).

After setting up a connection on 'api', from IRB; I can call;

```
api.create_brands({:name => "testcategory"})
```

which succeeds. I can also do brands(x number) which works.

If I try to call;

```
api.brands_count
```

which based on https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-ruby/blob/master/lib/bigcommerce/api.rb gives the brands_count method as;

```
def brands_count
  @connection.get '/brands/count'
end
```

I get undefined method 'brands_count'.

Same error with just straight 'brands';

```
api.brands({:min_id=>1,:max_id=>101})
```

and even the basic 'time' end point gives the error and I can't figure out why some things are working but others aren't.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Any chance api is nil?

Comment: If I do api.nil? it's false. Similarly, I'm entering the calls above into IRB one after the other, some are working, some aren't. Direct calls to Brands via Httparty work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had this issue with multiple endpoints; I ended up moving to using HTTParty directly.

I suspect I probably didn't check for JSON bodies or the correct headers; as I had to deal with these in HTTParty also.